# A/C malfunction

Tags: ac, hvac

What could cause the pipe out the compressor of the car to be too hot, I mean too hot to be touched with a bay hand, while the pipe after the condenser is slightly warm or rather normal.Then I noticed the cooling effect of the evaporator is slightly cool?

Comment: Is your AC working, or is there an issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Looks like you have a very high discharge pressure. The discharge pipe is normally hot, but it shouldn't be skin burning-hot. Perhaps there's insufficient airflow on the condenser and the subcooling is so low that the expansion device isn't being fed entirely with liquid and as a result the system barely cools...

Answer (score 0):

The compressor compresses the gas which raises its temperature (based on Boyles and Charles laws), goes to the condensor to be cooled.

The purpose of the evaporator is to provide cooling, so what is wrong with it being slightly cool?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe from compressor is always hot. Compressing refrigerant causes heat. Pipe from condenser should be cooler than pipe coming into condenser from compressor. See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/diagnose-ac-not-cooling-problems/) for temp measurements